# Complicated colour scheme definition in LESS / Joomla T3

Tags: less, joomla3.0

I'm building a site in Joomla 3 on T3 framework.

I'm having to use LESS for the first time, but am experienced with CSS.

The site will have differently themed landing pages.  These will all be identical except for the colour scheme.

I am attempting to set up a colour scheme in the T3 'variables' less file and then implement the colours - the colour will be different for many core components - such as H1, P, DIV Background Color, etc.

So if I set up, say, a master colour for Thailand's page, I create this rule in the variables.less file:

```
@thai: #e55092;
```

and then my knowledge of exactly how LESS compiles to CSS falls flat and I lose my entire train of thought.

Because I now want to be able to set up a landing page for Thailand in the T3 template.  I need to be able to use the class 'thai' in various places in this page - for instance, the `H1` text should be coloured #e55092, an `aside` background should be #e55092, an `HR` should be #e55092 ... for THIS page only.

I hope this isn't a too open question but what would be best practice for achieving this, keeping my code clean and fast?  My current line of thought is that I create a whole bunch of rules in LESS along the lines of:

```
thai.h1 { color: @thai }

thai.button [ background-color: @thai }
```

(excuse syntax - very new to LESS and not sure what's possible or correct)

But isn't that defeating the whole purpose of using LESS in the first place?

Comment: If the properties are different like in your above example (`color` for `h1` and `background-color` for `button`) then there is not much else you could do. If the properties are same then you can combine the selectors. Other than that and the usage of variables for the color, there is not much improvement that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is very broad indeed. Depending on your situation:

1. One CSS file for all pages. You can consider [changing selector order](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order) The code for a button can then look like that shown beneath:

   .button {
   border: 1px solid white;
   .thai & { background-color: red;}
   .japanese & { background-color: yellow;}
   }

In your HTML pages: `<body class="thai">` and so on..

2. Compile different CSS files for each landing page

In Less you can [override a variable by putting the definition afterwards](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-default-variables)
You should first define a main file, for the button example this button.less file should contain something like that shown below:

```
@button-background-color: orange;
button { background-color: @button-background-color; }
```

Now you can define you thai theme file (thai.less) as follows:

```
@import "button.less";
@button-background-color: red;
```

Or alternatively compile different CSS files using the [`modify-var` option](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-options):

```
lessc button.less --modify-var="button-background-color=red" thai.css
```